# How to check dynamic key in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have python dictionary which contains dynamic key.

For example:

```
{
    'gadget_1': 1, 'gadget_23': 4, 'manufacture_1': 6, 'manufacture_23': 3,
    'gadget_56': 34, 'name': 'xyz', 'price': 23, 'phone': '45345'
}
```

This is my dictionary in which key string will always be like '**gadget_**' or '**manufacture_**' and then it will have some sequence numbers from 1 to 100 or 200 as given in example.

So how can I get only those key that contains '**gadget_**' or '**manufacture_**'.

I know I can simply do it by loop, but its not a good way to go.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> d = {
    'gadget_1': 1, 'gadget_23': 4, 'manufacture_1': 6, 'manufacture_23': 3, 'gadget_56': 34,
    'name': 'xyz', 'price': 23, 'phone': '45345'
 }
>>> [k for k in d if k.startswith(('gadget_', 'manufacture_'))]
['gadget_23', 'gadget_56', 'manufacture_23', 'manufacture_1', 'gadget_1']
```

---

*Unrelated:*
wow i just noticed this is valid syntax in Python

```
[k for k in d if True if True if True]
['phone', 'gadget_23', 'gadget_56', 'manufacture_23', 'manufacture_1', 'gadget_1', 'price', 'name']
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a Regular Expression to make sure that you will not get false positives, like this

```
>>> data = {
    'gadget_1': 1, 'gadget_23': 4, 'manufacture_1': 6, 'manufacture_23': 3,
    'gadget_56': 34, 'name': 'xyz', 'price': 23, 'phone': '45345'
}
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(manufacture_|gadget_)\d+')
>>> [key for key in data if regex.match(key)]
['gadget_23', 'gadget_56', 'manufacture_23', 'manufacture_1', 'gadget_1']
```

The regular expression `(manufacture_|gadget_)\d+` makes sure that it matches any string which begins with either `manufacture_` or `gadget_` and followed by 1 or more decimal digits.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate with a loop, this function do the job, it's gets the dictionary and returns a dictionary with the keys that starts with gadget_ or manufacture_:

```
def get_by_keys(d):
    return {k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if k.startswith(('gadget_', 'manufacture_'))}
```